# How to use factorygirl to associate user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am learning to do tests using Rails testing tools, mainly: `rspec, factory_girl, shoulda, and faker` gems.

I want to test `has_one` and `belongs_to` associations. I have `user.rb` (with `name`) and `address.rb` (with `street`, `city`, and `user_id`) models.

I am trying to figure out how to create fake associations using fakers. I want to create a fake street and associate it with a fake user, but I can't figure out how to do it on `spec/factories/addresses.rb`

This is what I currently have:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :address do
    street    {Faker::Address.street_address}
    city      {Faker::Address.city}
    #Creates fake user and use that user's id for user_id)#
    user = build(:user, name: "Joe", id: 2)
    user_id   {user.id}
  end
end
```

This is the spec/models/address_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Address, type: :model do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    address = build(:address)
    expect(address).to be_valid
  end
  it {should belong_to(:user)}
end
```

When I run it, it shows `add_attribute': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2) (ArgumentError)` error. I tried removing the id on the argument and just did `user = build(:user, name: "Joe")` but the same error message still shows.

The test **passes** if I don't include the user lines on `addresses` factory. I confirmed that address has `belongs_to :user` and user has `has_one :address`.

Is it possible to generate fake association and associate address to a fake `user.id`? I would like to test `Address`'s `user_id` as well.

**Edit** - following are the related factories and models:

Factories

addresses.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :address do
    street    {Faker::Address.street_address}
    city      {Faker::Address.city}
    user
  end
end
```

users.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name      {Faker::Name.name}
  end
end
```

spec/models

address_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Address, type: :model do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    association user
    specific_user = build(:user, name: 'Joe')
    address = build(:address, specific_user)
    expect(address).to be_valid
  end
  it {should belong_to(:user)}
end
```

Error running address_spec.rb

```
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Address:0x00000001a94b00>
 # ./spec/models/addres
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the way you build association is incorrect. See https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations.

If you want a more specific associated user eg name: Joe, id: 2, it's probably better to do it in spec.

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :address do
    street    {Faker::Address.street_address}
    city      {Faker::Address.city}
    user
  end
end
```

Spec:

```
 it "has a valid factory" do
    specific_user = build(:user, name: 'Joe')
    address = build(:address, specific_user)
    expect(address).to be_valid
 end
```

Comment: I got this error `Trait not registered: #<User:0x00000005c96850>`. I added `association user` on spec, but now it shows `undefined local variable or method `user'`... Do you know what else am I missing?

Comment: You need to define a factory for `user`

Comment: I have `FactoryGirl.define do; factory :user do; name      {Faker::Address.name}; end; end` on factories/users.rb. Do I have to let `address` know that user exists somehow?

Comment: if `user_id` is in address model then that's all you need. Do you want to post all related factories and models into question?

Comment: hah, there's no `Faker::Address.name`, do you mean `Faker::Name.name`?

Comment: Woops! Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks, @kasperite! I just edited the original question.

Comment: is there `belongs_to :user` in `Address` model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123276/discussion-between-iggy-and-kasperite).